# How to operate Ubuntu OS file open dialog in Selenium

Tags: java, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

I have a tag with attributes:

```
<use xlink:href="/_ui/responsive/theme-aec/images/icon/svg-icon-sprite.svg#upload"></use>
```

that opens an OS Modal file dialog.

1. click link with xpath in selenium
   This is the xpath that is not found by chrome console but it already opens OS file dialog:

```
//use[@xlink:href='/_ui/responsive/theme-aec/images/icon/svg-icon-sprite.svg#upload']
```

2. how to operate file dialog from Ubuntu OS in selenium? This snippet does open the file dialog, but does not upload the mentioned file:

```
WebElement addFile = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='file']"));
addFile.sendKeys("/home/azureuser/Development/workspace/aec-s1-desktop-ui-testing/src/test/resources/test.png");
```

Thanks in advance!

I expected the 2. snippet from above to:

- upload the given file in Ubuntu OS file open dialog box
- subsequently close the Ubuntu OS file open dialog box

Actually the file is not uploaded and file open dialog box stays active

---

**Update:**
The path of the file is actually given to the website widget, but the dialog box does not disappear even when calling `submit()`:
`addFile.submit();`

Answer (score 0):

This is doing the trick:

```
WebElement addFile = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='file']"));
addFile.sendKeys("/home/azureuser/Development/workspace/aec-s1-desktop-ui-testing/src/test/resources/test.jpg");
```

BEWARE: do not open the dialog window - directly send the file path to the widget!